# Ignore header mismatch rejects with patch command

Tags: cvs, patch

While applying a patch with cvs, the only rejects I have are due to file header mismatches. I knew of an option to ignore such rejects but couldn't figure out now.

The rejects look something like this. Does someone knows how to avoid such rejects?

```
! // -*--*-    $Revision: 1.48 $
! // Last checked in by $Author: foo $ on $Date: ... $

  /*****************************************************************
   *
***************
*** 1,5 ****
! // -*--*-     $Revision: 1.14 $
! //  Last checked in by $Author: foo $  on $Date: .... $

  /*****************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get `patch` to ignore CVS keywords but you can bypass them completely by using the `-kk` parameter when you generate the diff. eg.

```
cvs rdiff -kk ...
```

From the documentation on [keyword substitution](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_12.html#SEC103):

> -kk
>
> Generate only keyword names in keyword strings; omit their values. For example, for the Revision keyword, generate the string $Revision$ instead of $Revision: 5.7 $. This option is useful to ignore differences due to keyword substitution when comparing different revisions of a file (see section Merging and keywords).